# How to get pictures of the camera preview, before its Callback draws theese pictures to its holder?

Tags: android

I really hope you guys could help me, because I couldn't find no solution for my task since 2 weeks now, neither by searching, nor by myself.

What I'm trying to do is to get the camera-preview-pictures in bitmap format, before they are drawn to the camera-preview's surfaceView!, then I want to manipulate the bitmap with computer-vision-algorithms, and eventually draw them on the camera-preview's surfaceView.

I'm able to get YuvImages from the camera-preview using the callback's `onPreviewFrame()`method, further I'm able to manipulate them as needed and I'm able to draw pictures on a surfaceView using a thread. But I can't figure out how to combine those tasks.
The problem is that the preview's callback automatically draws it's pictures to its surfaceView, so when I get the pictures in the `onPreviewFrame()` method, they were already drawn to the surfaceView. How to change this behaviour?

I could find no solution. I thought it might be a workaround simply not showing the preview's surfaceView, but another one, where the manipulated pictures are drawn on, but I couldn't get this solution working either...

I hope you guys could help me, because I'm already frustrated.

Comment: Hi. This answer is from a similar subject: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6478375/how-can-i-manipulate-the-camera-preview. The example has a line with: "// This allows us to make our own draw".